# How do I transfer my files to google drive mount via terminal, Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: bash, mount, 19.04, google-drive

Under *Settings* → *Online Accounts* I am able to connect my gmail account, which allows me to mount my google drive as a network drive. The path of the mount was found by opening a terminal within the mount window. It is given by:

```
/run/user/1000/gvfs/google-drive:host=gmail.com,user=gmail_user_name
```

I am trying to write a `crontab` background process which syncs specified folders from my home directory every so often. I do so by using the following bash script to transfer specified directories into the mounted network drive.

```
#!/bin/bash
googledrive_dir=/run/user/1000/gvfs/google-drive:host=gmail.com,user=gmail_user_name
dir_cat='Admin'

for name in $dir_cat
do
    rsync -avhz ~/$name $googledrive_dir/ --delete
done
```

Upon running the bash script, the files inside the directories within each specified folder in `dir_cat` are deleted. And I get an output error, shown below:

```
sending incremental file list
rsync: failed to set times on "/run/user/1000/gvfs/google-drive:host=gmail.com,user=google_user_name/Admin": Operation not supported (95)
deleting Admin/19sZNc-h9o1u65ZT5ANXyKXgQVEzU92Th
Admin/
Admin/cubicle_name_tag.odt
rsync: mkstemp "/run/user/1000/gvfs/google-drive:host=gmail.com,user=google_user_name/Admin/.cubicle_name_tag.odt.Que9bQ" failed: Operation not supported (95)

sent 11.68K bytes  received 377 bytes  3.44K bytes/sec
total size is 13.12K  speedup is 1.09
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1207) [sender=3.1.3]
```

How should I resolve this problem?

Comment: `failed to set times: ... Operation not supported` indicates that something doesn't work with times for the gdrive file system. So you might want to remove `-a` option. Also you might try first without `-z` ...

Comment: removing ```-a``` results in the following error :

```rsync: --delete does not work without --recursive (-r) or --dirs (-d).

rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1596) [client=3.1.3]
```

Comment: I have tried using ```-r``` instead of ```-a```, and it resulted in the script deleting all the folders in google drive folder and then uploading them